# Gnome extensions under 20.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I had difficulty upgrading to 20.04 from 19.10 but eventually succeeded, however all of my Gnome extensions apart from "Desktop Icons" are switched off. If I switch them on nothing happens and after a reboot they are all off again except for "Desktop Icons".

(If I turn "Desktop Icons" off it switches back on again. If I switch "Desktop Icons NG (DING)" on it switches itself back off and "Desktop Icons" switches back on again.", but this is not the main problem I have. I mention it as additional information only))

I am running Ubuntu on Wayland and all of my Gnome extensions worked inder 19.10. Is there a known problem with Gnome extensions on 20.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you looking/setting the extensions on/off?

When I updated to 20.04 there seemed to be a new `Extensions` app which had a main on/off at the top and individual on/off settings. And also in Gnome `Tweaks` app in the `Extensions` section has the same. Clicking the main top on/off switch on one seems to affect the other but the same is not true for the extension on/off switches.

If I use the new `Extensions` app (so far) my extensions seem to work o.k.

Comment: I am turning them on/off at https://extensions.gnome.org/ https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ Where do I download the new extensions app from?

Comment: I switched the extensions on in the Gnome-Tweak tool and evetything is fine now!